# Category Navigation suddenly disappeared

Tags: magento2, category, navigation, varnish

Sorry in advance I'm not very familiar with Magento.

I am working on a Magento Web Shop and one day the top navigation, where you can open the categories, just disappeared. I tried searching in the vendor folder for the Block or templates for it but no success there. Didn't find a solution in the Admin panel as well. Searched in Google, but the only thing I found was about Varnish, which I'm not using.

I'm open to any suggestions and questions.

Comment: Share the website url

Comment: I'm developing local